# removeValue() deletes but automatically adds back the deleted values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The data was removed but it was added back immediately. THis code was placed inside the code for checking of credentials(supposedly will check for users credential before deleting the items). I have tried putting it as a separate code with just the use of a button and it works. But why does the glitch occurs?

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = ref.child("posts").orderByChild("userid").equalTo(uid);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot Snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you log `databaseError` in onCancelled?

Comment: What does `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` print?

Comment: @AlexMamo it didnt print out anything as the data was successfully deleted but re-added somehow. I couldnt find any error in the logcat